# select em elementos que não estão na array

Tags: php, array, select

Tenho uma array em PHP com IDs:

```
$idNaoEnvia['1', '3', '6']
```

E uma tabela chamada **conta** em MYSQL:

```
ID |  NOME
1  |  caio
2  |  antonio
3  |  cleber
4  |  marcos
5  |  leonardo
6  |  andre
```

Queria usando PDO dar um select na tabela **conta** apenas nos nomes que **NÃO** estão nessa array. A resposta que espero seria:

antonio, marcos, leonardo

É possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o `NOT IN` para filtrar e o `implode` para converter o `array` em string, separado por vírgula.

Pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$idNaoEnvia = ['1', '3', '6'];
$sql = 'select ID, NOME from comta where ID not in (' . implode(',', $idNaoEnvia) . ');';
echo $sql;
```

Resultado:

> select ID, NOME from comta where ID not in (1,3,6);